# Interface Vpc Endpoint - Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

We have VPC Endpoint enabled for several AWS services for example: execute-api for API Gateway. I would like to log all the api calls made to VPC Endpoint into CloudWatch, is there a way?

A couple of things that I can think of:

- VPC Flow Logs contains just the IP addresses which is not enough,
- CloudTrail doesn't log these.

I can log at individual service level for example API Gateway Logs, however, if incorrect requests are made to VPC Endpoint and they won't reach the final service in this case API Gateway and there is not trace I can find on what requests are made with that parameters.

Please let me know if I am missing options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such log exists. VPC Endpoints is pure network configuration so no Data Plane service exists. You can only use VPC flow logs to debug. Also, connectivity between VPC Endpont and service is under AWS responsibility so you have no visibility of that part.

Comment: I'm not sure that entirely true. VPC Endpoint can have a Policy attached, and that policy may cause the Endpoint to terminate connection before it even reaches the actual AWS Service. In this case, there's not even a CloudTrail Event logged that would show that the request was attempted, only the 403 response to client. In this context, VPC Endpoint seems to be something like a reverse-proxy, with active policy checking on each request.